# No of documents in a view of couchdb using nano

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

As i am new to Node js ,could anyone please help me to provide procedure to find number of documents in a view of couchdb using nano.
for example , I have view '_design/settings/_view/settings' in couch db .Using nano i want to find no of documents present in this view.

Answer (score 0):

When you query a view using nano, provide empty arrays for `startkey` and `endkey` parameters. This will return all the results in the view.The response will contain a `total_rows` variable which is the total number of results.